# Month, Year and Between in SQL together

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column `IH_Date` with data type `Date`, which stores full date information including day. User will enter only `from & to (from month, from year, to month, to year)`. The query should return the respective results.

I write this query with some online help it works fine but it is not an efficient & it is slow sometime. Does anyone have better solution.

Help will be appreciated.

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_item_history IH
WHERE YEAR(IH.IH_Date) * 100 + MONTH(IH.IH_Date)
BETWEEN 2022 * 100 + 03
    AND 2023 * 100 + 02
ORDER BY IH.IH_DATE ASC
```

Comment: Change to use `>=` and '<' .  `WHERE IH.IH_Date >= '20220301' AND IH.IH_DATE < '20230301'`

Comment: I don't understand, could you please help me out more!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Avoid converting every row of data into year and month values. Instead of converting the data to suit your parameter types, convert the parameters values into dates, and I suggest [DATEFROMPARTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datefromparts-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) for this. This way an index on `IH_Date` can be leveraged by your query.

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_item_history IH
WHERE IH.IH_Date >= DATEFROMPARTS(@FromYear,@FromMonth,1)
AND IH.IH_Date < DATEFROMPARTS(@ToYear,@ToMonth,1)
ORDER BY IH.IH_DATE ASC
```

**Note** you may need to add 1 month to the latter date so that the "To Month" is "inclusive". i.e.

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_item_history IH
WHERE IH.IH_Date >= DATEFROMPARTS(@FromYear,@FromMonth,1)
AND IH.IH_Date < DATEADD(month,1,DATEFROMPARTS(@ToYear,@ToMonth,1))
ORDER BY IH.IH_DATE ASC
```